# Настройка nginx и upstream

Tags: nginx

Тупейший вопрос, где-то явно накосячил, где - понять не могу.  Есть nginx и приложение на thin. Thin правильно отображается по любому uri, кроме /, в случае доступа к корню nginx и не думает смотреть upstream, только файлы index.html / index.html (судя по error_log debug). ЧЯДНТ?Конфа:

```
upstream redmine {
    server unix:path/redmine/tmp/sockets/thin.0.sock;
    server unix:path/redmine/tmp/sockets/thin.1.sock;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name redmine.domain.tld;
    root path/redmine/public;
    access_log path/redmine/log/access.log;
    error_log path/redmine/log/error.log;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @upstream;
    }
    location @upstream {
        proxy_pass http://redmine;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была вот в этом:

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ @upstream;
```

До сих пор не знаю, что за этим стоит, но nginx валился на проверке директории и дальше не шел. Когда я убрал `$uri/`, всё заработало.